# Oracle Apex 4.2.4 Display only fields not saved to database

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using a dynamic action to auto fill data into fields based on the ID of a person that is being pulled from another table (which pulls the person's dept, employee#, etc). This works fine if I leave the auto populated fields editable, but I want these fields to be 'display only' so that the person entering the data cannot edit it.  That's the whole reason for using dynamic action.  When I set the fields to 'display only', the data never gets saved to the table so the fields are blank when I run a report on the record.  Is there a way to get these fields to populate the database and still not be editable.  Do I need to run another process 'behind the scenes' to get them populated, like with an 'on submit' process?

Comment: Did you try to autofill data using default values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **Text** field and then set the **"HTML Form Element Attributes**" with **readonly="readonly";**.

Comment: I just typed  'readonly' in the HTML Form attribute field and it worked.  I could not find a readonly in the pop up LOV--not sure why.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create an additional hidden item and save it instead of the read only item. Assign your dynamic actions to alter the values on both items, the read only and the hidden ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve an update-able display/read only item by setting the item **Display as** property to **Text Field** and setting the **Read Only Condition Type** of the item to **Always**.

[image]