# APEX validation on display only field

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a question about the validations of APEX.

I have 2 display only fields. One has the value 17 en the other 16. The validation is that the display only field with number 17 can't be larger than the display only field with number 16. I use the function returning boolean. 
My PL/SQL code is:

```
  IF to_number( :P2_TEST ) > to_number( :P2_WR_MAX_UREN )
  THEN
    RETURN false;
  ELSE
    RETURN true;
  END IF;
```

When I execute the page with the button, then it don't show the error. What is the problem?

```
:P2_TEST = 17
:P2_WR_MAX_UREN = 16
```

Comment: See this question for a workaround:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273509/oracle-apex-4-2-4-display-only-fields-not-saved-to-database

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your display only fields does not save the values into session state. 
You can fix this by editing your fields and at Settings select Yes for Save Session State.